# Positioning under absolute positioned divs

Tags: css, positioning, css-position

I have 4 divs containing images, absolute positioned totalling 100% width.

This is due to the user wanting to use the full width of the page in all browsers.

I need to position a div underneath it, also with 100% width, which expands/contracts at the same rate with the browser.

I understand floating isn't an option.

Desired layout:

```
[img1][img2][img3][img4]
[       content        ]
-------100% width-------
```

HTML

```
     <div id="container">
          <div id="image1"><img src="images/1.jpg"></div>
          <div id="image2"><img src="images/2.jpg"></div>
          <div id="image3"><img src="images/3.jpg"></div>
          <div id="image4"><img src="images/4.jpg"></div>
        </div>

     <div id="content">
     </div>
```

CSS:

```
#container{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
}

#image1 {
       width: 25%;
      position: absolute;
      right: 50%;   
}
#image2 {
    width: 25%;
    position: absolute;
     right: 75%;

#image3 {
    width: 25%;
    position: absolute;
     left: 50%;
}
#image4 {
    width: 25%;
    position: absolute;
     left: 75%;
}

#content {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Why absolute is necessary? And why float is not an option?

Comment: From what I Understand, floating won't work as absolute positioned elements are taken out of the workflow. If there is a way to allow 100% width with image resizes with floats what would be great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Used to this method**

**[Live Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/ukYkcXFo)**  ----------------------------  **[Demo-two](http://tinkerbin.com/Syw5tK8Y)**

**Css**

```
#pic-container{
font-size:0;
}
#pic-container img{
width:25%;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

**HTML**

```
   <div class="container">
     <div id="pic-container">
 <img src="images/1.jpg">
<img src="images/2.jpg">
<img src="images/3.jpg">
<img src="images/4.jpg">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="container">
                herer is the your content         
     </div>
```

**[Live Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/ukYkcXFo)**

Comment: Wow. I made it way too complicated! Just testing on local install

Comment: What does font-size:0 do to images?

Comment: Thanks. Could you recommend any learning materials for "advanced" positioning?

Comment: Welcome and check to this link and now learn more about position http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/110-quick-overview-of-css-position-values/

Comment: are you online for a quick job?

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong look at your CSS code:

> you forget to put closing "}" of your #image2 .
>   it must look like this now.

```
#image2 {
  width: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 75%;
 }
```

> hope it helps.